# Creating a table directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I'm kind of new to AngularJS but I'm trying to create a simple table directive however I can't quite figure out what's the best way of doing it.

This is what I've got for the directive file:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('hantera')

.directive('bsGrid', function($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl:'views/bsGrid.html',
        replace: true, 
        scope: {
            data: '='
        }
    };
});
```

And this is my template file:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">{{key}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
            <td ng-repeat="cell in row">
                {{cell}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What issues are you facing?

Comment: Well the headers aren't really working. Seems to be kinda working when I replace data with data[0] but I don't know if that's really the best way of doing it.